# how many2many defined for custom module

Tags: odoo

I tried to use many2many relational field in my custom module "notebook". Code is given below:

notebook.py:

```
from osv import fields, osv
import time

class notebook(osv.osv):
    _name = "notebook"
    _description = "Simple Notebook"
    _columns = {
        'title' : fields.char('Title', size=30, required=True),
        'tag_ids': fields.many2many(
                    'hello',
                    'title',
                    'name',
                    string="Tags"
                                ),
    }

notebook()

class hello(osv.osv):
    _name = 'hello'
    _columns = {
            'name':fields.char('Name',size=30),
            'note_ids': fields.many2many(
                                'notebook',
                                'name',
                                'title',
                                string="Notebooks"
                                        ),
                    } 
hello()
```

notebook_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="notebook_form_view">
            <field name="name">notebook.form</field>
            <field name="model">notebook</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Notebook">
                    <field name="title" />
                    <field name="tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_notebook_form">
            <field name="name">notebook</field>
            <field name="res_model">notebook</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem name="NotebookParent" icon="terp-project" id="NotebookParent_menu" />

        <menuitem name="NotesChild" parent="NotebookParent_menu" id="NotesChild_menu" />

        <menuitem name="Header" parent="NotesChild_menu" id="Header_menu_mainform"
            action="action_notebook_form" />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

hello_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hello_form_view">
            <field name="name">hello.form</field>
            <field name="model">hello</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Hello Form">
                    <field name="name" select="1" />
                    <field name="note_ids" widget="many2many_list"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

There is no error in installing and the fields are also displayed and data is stored in the Database.

My problem arises as inter-relationship between note_ids and tag_ids is not proper.

Example:

```
If I have a notebook record as :
       title = sample
       tags = tag1, tag2
 The tags are created in hello record as:
       tag1 record:
           name="tag1"
           Notebooks = ""
       tag2 record:
           name="tag2"
           Notebooks= ""
```

Why is the relationship not maintained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at your many2many
It should be like this

```
fields.many2many('that object name',
             'sql relation table name',
             'this object id',
             'that object id',
             'Field Lable')
```

Eg: in your case the two many2many could be like this

first many2many

```
'tag_ids': fields.many2many(
                'hello',
                'notebook_hello_rel',
                'notebook_id',
                'hello_id',
                string="Tags"
                            ),
```

Second many2many

```
'note_ids': fields.many2many(
                            'notebook',
                            'notebook_hello_rel',
                            'hello_id',
                            'notebook_id',
                            string="Notebooks"
                                    ),
```

Comment: Thanks Sinoj, the relationship is working fine...

Can you explain what is "notebook_hello_rel"?

Is it a variable available in DB or python object or a temporary variable

Comment: for a many2many, we will need additional Table in DB to keep all the reference. notebook_hello_rel will be the table name and it will have two column "hello_id" which is a reference to "hello" table and "notebook_id" which is a reference to "notebook" table.

Comment: the relationship object is created automatically?

Comment: K thanks. so hello_id and notebook_id are two field name created in DB of notebook_hello_rel, so the name of the identifier can be named randomly?

Comment: hello_id and notebook_id are two column created on new new table notebook_hello_rel on your DB.
You can give any name, but if you look in to my example, you will see that the usage of the two column names are interchanged in the many2many definitions.

Comment: Thanks I faced the same problem, your answer solved it.