# How to show a column on a one2many field (kanban mode) in OpenERP?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I've created the models `boy` and `girl` (both with attributes *name*, *surname*, *age*), which are related to the table `love_date` (*boy_id*, *girl_id*, *relationship_level*).

The model `boy` has a one2many column (*love_dates*) which points to `love_date` through the field `boy_id`. Same to model `girl` through the field `girl_id`. The model `love_date` has the fields `boy_id` and `girl_id` which are many2one pointing to the models `boy` and `girl`.

Now I've introduced my enviroment, I'll explain the problem:

I'm on the form of a `boy`, I'm showing his `love_dates` in a kanban view (just like the tab *Contacts* of the form of *res.partner* if you see it anytime).

The problem is that I can't show the data of girls who dated the current boy.

```
<field name="love_dates" mode="kanban">
    <kanban>
        <field name="boy_id"/>
        <field name="girl_id"/>
        <field name="relationship_type"/>
        <templates>
        <t t-name="kanban-box">
            <a t-if="! read_only_mode" type="delete" style="position: absolute; right: 0; padding: 4px; display: inline-block">X</a>
            <div class="oe_module_vignette">
                <a type="open">
                    <t t-if="record.girl_id.has_image === true">
                        <img t-att-src="kanban_image('girl', 'image_small', record.girl_id.id.value)" class="oe_avatar oe_kanban_avatar_smallbox"/>
                    </t>
                    <t t-if="record.girl_id.image !== false">
                        <img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,'+record.girl_id.image" class="oe_avatar oe_kanban_avatar_smallbox"/>
                    </t>
                </a>
                <div class="oe_module_desc">
                    <div class="oe_kanban_box_content oe_kanban_color_bglight oe_kanban_color_border">
                        <table class="oe_kanban_table">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="oe_kanban_title1" align="left" valign="middle">
                                    <h4>
                                        <a type="open">
                                                <t t-esc="record.girl_id.name"/>
                                                <t t-esc="record.girl_id.surname"/>
                                                <t t-esc="record.girl_id.age"/>
                                                <t t-esc="record.relationship_type"/>
                                        </a>
                                    </t>
                                </td>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </kanban>
</field>
```

I'm not able to see the image of the girls, the surname, the age... I can only see their names and relationship types.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how many2many defined for custom module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021105/how-many2many-defined-for-custom-module)

Comment: I've read the other post, but it's not the same question. In my case the relationships are one2many and many2one, in the case of the other question the relationship is a many2many which was declared without a comodel name in both tables. Thank you anyway for the suggestion.